# Add X lines to end of string, removing same number of lines from the start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large string that is displayed in a text area. The string is separated into lines using \n. New lines are constantly appended to the string as the program runs.

To prevent the program from slowing down to much or crashing the browser, I want to never display more than 10k lines of text. To do this, I want to delete from the start of the string however many lines I add to the end. How can I do this?

Ex:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
...
line 9,999
line 10,000
```

Then the string is updated with 3 new lines of data

```
line 4
line 5
...
line 9,999
line 10,000
line 10,001
line 10,002
line 10,003
```

Just to clarify I am NOT moving lines from the start to the end of the string. I am adding totally different lines to the end, and removing the same number of lines from the start.

I currently have this:

```
function(addedText){
//prevent updating/refresh textarea with blank strings
if(addedText.length !== 0){}
    //"#log-data" is an HTML textarea that displays all the text 
    //that is appended to it each time this function runs

    x = number of lines in addedText

    //Add addedText to the textarea
    $("#log-data").append(addedText);

    REMOVE x lines from start of "#log-data"
});
```

Comment: It's not a big deal.
Please put your code. Then, we can recorrect it

Comment: Split on newlines, and shift, slice, splice, whatever from the start of the array

Comment: apart from splitting as suggested in other answers and splicing the first 3 entries, since you have 10k of lines, it might be more convenient to  just use `string.replace(/(.*\n){3}/,'')` - 3 is the line quantity

Comment: @Mojtaba. I'm not sure what you mean. I did put in my code. Stuff like "REMOVE x lines from start of #log-data" is a placeholder for code I have not written, since most solutions I found prior seemed like they would be way too slow with 10k lines.

Comment: @maioman, I will try that... but I think the solutions in the other question (this is marked as a duplicate) will work. The question is almost identical to mine, too bad I did not see it before.

Thanks. Will report back when a solution is found!

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot
I meant, if we could have the exact codes, we could give you the exact working answer ;) . There's no problem.
However, I provided a sample code which you can customize it based on yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text = jQuery("#textarea_id").val().split("\n");

var x = number of lines in addedText //Taken from question

for(var i=0; i < x; i++) {
  text.shift();
  text.push(addedText[i]); //Hoping addedText is array(if not, can be passed as array by converting it using split);
}

jQuery("#textarea_id").val(text.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can do the remove process before appending new lines.
Something like this:

```
totalLines = $("#log-data").html().split('<br>');
totalLines.splice(0,x);
$("#log-data").html(totalLines.join('<br>'));
```

However, it's better to have your code. Then, maybe there were better way